# Is there a way to get a Java program to run during a certain time of day?

Tags: java

I am just curious on if it would be possible to write a java application and then have it run automatically during a certain time of day??

For example: If I had a program that would like open a text file and write the current date in it and then close. Would it be possible for me to get it to run at say 8:00 A.M. everyday without me having to run it?

Comment: you can use task scheduler if it is in windows

Comment: You sure need cron, task scheduler ou something even more robust like UC4. I don't think looping with thread sleep or calculating the thread sleep time until you need to wake up is a good solution, as if something goes wrong in the meantime you'll never have your code actually executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a batch job scheduler, eg. `cron` on *nix or Windows scheduler. It can easily trigger your program to run at the desired time.

Otherwise, you could write a long running Java program that detects when 8am has rolled around and perform your desired action.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check janos♦'s answer below to Executing a task at a particular time in the morning using ScheduledExecutorService, hope it will help good luck...

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63520/executing-a-task-at-a-particular-time-in-the-morning-using-scheduledexecutorserv